# How to develop and make a Bigcommerce app

Tags: bigcommerce

I want create an affiliate application for Bigcommerce to interact with my store. I trying to use API but it's not work proper.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show what you tried and where it failed? If you don't know what I mean, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on https://developer.bigcommerce.com/ to build an app.
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/building-apps-bigcommerce/building-apps

If you need help with a specific API, try posting the details of the request, and what you're trying to do.